# Validating values in testng groups attribute

Tags: testng

I want to validate the values of the 'groups' attribute of @Test in testng. This is basically to avoid any human error. For example how can I make sure that if a test has groups attribute, the value of it must only be from a known list.

Is this possible to validate before starting the testng tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look through IMethodInterceptor or IAnnotationTransformer interfaces
Here is the answer to a similar question
[Is it possible to put a condition to TestNG to run the test if that is member of two groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686636/is-it-possible-to-put-a-condition-to-testng-to-run-the-test-if-that-is-member-of)